# ZeroMQ/JeroMQ publish one message on multiple topics

Tags: zeromq

Is it possible for zmq pub socket to publish same message on multiple topics? Or put another way is it possible for a sub socket to match one of the many prefixes in a pub/sub envelope's header frames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is "no" -- the SUB socket does prefix matching on the first frame only.